# Assets in Laravel 4 not loading

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, laravel, assets

I'm learning Laravel 4.1 and cannot get any assets to load. No CSS, images etc.

```
File structure
-app
-bootstrap
-public
    -assets
       -css
          -main.css
       -images
         -foo.jpg
    index.php
-vendor
```

in Views

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/foo.jpg')}}" />
```

also have used the HTML::style

Image shows in source code fine and image is there but will not load, not even direct in browser. So I believe its an htaccess issue but I am using the default one from installation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have been using wamp server and php serve but nothing works. Path is correct and I have tried all combinations of paths. Cannot even access a php file directly in browser.

Any help very much apprieciated.

Comment: your htaccess looks fine to me. if you're serving your site through `php artisan serve` you should get information of possible misroutings. otherwise under `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` is the same logging. can you access different routes? like try creating in your routes.php `Route::get('/test', function() { return 'works'; });`

Comment: What do you get in the browser if you view source for the image?

Comment: I went back a version in my project, and it now works. Have no idea where it was failing but thanks for looking. Gotta get my ead down and finish this project and then look to find the bug.